# Is componentDidMount triggered everytime I set state somewhere in the class?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, state, listener

I would like to know if `componentDidMount` gets triggered every time I setState(anywhere in the class)?

Second, I am calling a function `fetchData` inside `componentDidMount`, and `fetchData` is a database listener so it listens for changes in `Firestore` database. How is that called every time if I call it from `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect.  I suggest reading:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I answered your first question below. For your second question I recommend you open a new post, and then include the [minimal code that reproduces what you're doing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I asked the second question in another post, can you check it out?

Comment: when you update your state, `componentDidUpdate` is a good place to catch the event.

Comment: @O.o is that a good place to put a database listener?

Comment: How do you get db content?

Comment: @O.o check the question here, I just posted with other details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61314627/how-does-a-firestore-onsnapshot-listens-for-changes-in-react-native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `componentDidMount` is called when the component is first added to the DOM (or render tree when on native), not when that component is subsequently updated/rerendered.

From the React docs on [state and lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html):

> The `componentDidMount()` method runs after the component output has been rendered to the DOM. This is a good place to set up a timer...

And the documentation on [`Component.componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

> `componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

Setting state merely causes the component to be rerendered.