# How does a Firestore onSnapshot listens for changes in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have seen in multiple places people placing the listener code inside the `componentDidMount`, however, I am wondering how does it work since `componentDidMount` is called only once, therefor, it should fetch only once. How does it fetches again when changes happen in Firestore?

**Example code :**

```
componentDidMount() {
  if(this.state.screen === 7){
        var query = firestore().collection('Collection').doc().collection('subcollection');
            query = query.where('act', '==', 1);
            query = query.where('city', '==', this.state.selected_city);
            query = query.orderBy('update_time', 'desc');
            query = query.limit(10);

            query.onSnapshot({
                error: (e) => this.setState({ errorMessage: e, refreshingPatients: false }),
                next: (querySnapshot) => {
                    var dataSource = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => { return { ...doc.data(), doc_id: doc.id } });                       
                    var lastVisiblePatient = dataSource[dataSource.length - 1].doc_id;
                    this.setState({
                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        lastVisiblePatient: lastVisiblePatient,
                        refreshingPatients: false,
                    });
                },
            });
    }
 }
```

**EDIT**: added an example code. I want to listen to changes of Firestore DB all the time. Is that the correct way of doing it? If yes, how does it work because `componentDidMount` is only called once? 
Note: I am only listening to Firestore when screen state is set to 7.

Comment: Maybe you could edit the question to show examples of the code that you're confused about?  Don't leave us guessing about what you're talking about. Be sure to look for similar code that might unregister the listener.

Comment: @DougStevenson sorry, I just edited and added an example code. Let me know if the question is still not clear.

Comment: yes, componentDidUpdate is a good choice

Comment: also do you set your initial state with some values from other place?

Comment: @O.o When the app starts I set state to 0, later on I set state to 7 so obviously code in `componentDidMount` never fetches from db.

Comment: your componentDidMount has got no meanings then. Just change to componentDidUpdate.

Answer (score 1):

Your `componentDidMount` is indeed only called once, but you're attaching a *permanent* listener in there. So the handler that you specify in `onSnapshot.next` is called right away with the initial data from the database, and after that each time that the data matching the query changes.

Comment: Aha! So, I can actually call a function with that listener code from anywhere else and that listener will be active permanently, right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment correctly. I you want to move the code that attaches the listener (`query.onSnapshot({...})`) into a function, and call that from `componentDidMount`, then that will indeed work the exact same.

Comment: I mean what if I dont call it from `componentDidMount` but from another function?

Comment: That depends on what other function that is, and if that function is already invoked. I recommend reading https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html to learn about the component lifecycle in React, and what methods of your component are invoked automatically at what point.

Comment: Here is a simple example: I click button Fetch which calls `_myFunction` which then calls `_fetchDataListener`. So, will that listener keep listening permanently once I have called it from `_myFunction` ?

Comment: Yes. By the way: if you're new to this I recommend just giving it a try. You have most of the code already, and it'll both teach you more and get you the answer much faster than we can do here.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution1:**
Read the comment inside the code.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevState, prevProps) {
  if(prevState !== this.state.screen && this.state.screen === 7) {

        var query = firestore().collection('Collection').doc().collection('subcollection');
            query = query.where('act', '==', 1);
            query = query.where('city', '==', this.state.selected_city);
            query = query.orderBy('update_time', 'desc');
            query = query.limit(10);

            query.onSnapshot({
                error: (e) => this.setState({ errorMessage: e, refreshingPatients: false }),
                next: (querySnapshot) => {
                    var dataSource = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => { return { ...doc.data(), doc_id: doc.id } });                       
                    var lastVisiblePatient = dataSource[dataSource.length - 1].doc_id;
                    this.setState({

                    // you are not updating screen so it is always 7
                    // if you update other state variables, it will trigger ComponentDidUpdate again, 
                    // and again and again and again

                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        lastVisiblePatient: lastVisiblePatient,
                        refreshingPatients: false,
                    });
                },
            });
    }
 }
```

By adding `prevState !== this.state.screen`, you can prevent `componentDidUpdate` being triggered everytime you update other states.

Like dataSource, lastVisiblePatient, and refreshingPatients.

**Solution 2:** Since you are using class components, you can use setState callback.

```
this.setState({screen: newValue}, doSomethingNew);

doSomethingNew(){
     if (this.state.screen === 7) {
         // your code goes here
     }
}
```

the callback function(here `doSomethingNew`) is triggered after `screen` value is updated with `newValue`.

**Solution3:** If you convert to function component, you can use `useEffect` dependency.

```
const [screen, setScreen] = useState(initialValue);    
useEffect(() => {
    if (screen === 7) {
        //do something here
    }
}, [screen]);    // adding screen as a dependency means this  useEffect is triggered only when screen value is changed.
```

Comment: Those are some nice solutions, thanks! However, check what @Frank van Puffelen said above, he said that listener is permanent so once its called it will be listening permanently. that means I dont even have to use any `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate` at all. At least that's how I understand.

Comment: then why did you add `this.state.screen===7`?

Comment: Because I dont want that listener to be called if for ex. user has only been to screen 1 or 2 or 3 and so on. I want it to be called only when the user enter screen 7 and then keep listening from then on.

Comment: then you need a `componentDidUpdate` - you will add a permanent listener when `screen === 7`, and since you don't need a listener anymore, you will have to add a flag variable so that you shouldn't make another listener later. Imagine that user selects 7 at first, and 3 and 7 again.

Comment: why not like this: Click button to go to screen7 --> button calls `_goToScreen7()` which setState screen : 7 and calls `_startListeningToDb()` ?

Comment: can't click the button again? if users clicks again, it will open another listener...

Comment: Damn, didn't think about that! So you are saying whenever I call that  listener it doesn't reset but instead creates a second listener?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212088/discussion-between-o-o-and-cooldude).